# PHP front-end for installing Django

Tags: php, python, django

A simple question:

1. Is this possible?
2. Is it worth the time looking into it?

Comment: What exactly would this do? Use a PHP script to install the Python Django script? If so, what exactly would be the point?

Comment: Why would you want this? Django is a framework, not a content management system or blog platform. It's intended for developers, not end-users. Installation should be straightforward for anyone who is familiar enough with Python to consider a framework worthwhile. If you need a "PHP front end" (to a Python-based platform?!), you're looking at the wrong product.

Comment: In defense of the OP - there are many management systems and platforms (cPanel, etc) which install frameworks and platforms of many varieties and flavors.  Why not a PHP front-end to install a framework, like Django?

Comment: The front end would not be for developing purposes, just for configuring database name, server, media root, etc.

Comment: For example, lets say we develop something using django. The average end-user is not going to understand how to install this on his server - in such a case a frontend which configures settings.py and does syncdb would be of great help.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a server management tool like webmin http://www.webmin.com/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably bundle Django with your project - or the parts of it that are needed. Users of your product will need to have python and the necessary libs installed. That is not something that you can do via PHP. Well, you could, but that would be like Webmin. When making a product for sale or for users to install, this is always something to think about before starting. In fact, at times, this very restriction is the most important deciding factor when choosing a technology and designing the system. Why is XYZ popular in the first place?